# How to create a rounded first and last viewcell in ListView Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, xamarin.forms, cornerradius

I want to create a `ListView` mentioned in the picture below. The problem is that I don't want to create a full rounded `ListView`. I just want a rectangle shape `ListView` Header and the rounded first and last `ViewCell`? Can anyone tell me how to do that?

[image: Rounded ViewCell Example Image]

Comment: What platforms are you targeting?

Comment: Android and IOS by using Xamarin Forms

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this type


  <ListView x:Name="lstView"
            BackgroundColor="White"
            HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="0,10,0,15">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="10" />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="{Binding Image}" />
                            <StackLayout Grid.Column="2" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="#f36e22" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding Text}" TextColor="Black" />
                            </StackLayout>
                            <Image Grid.Column="3" Source="{Binding smallImage}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Please, comment your code.
It's not possible to understand what you are trying to achieve with your answer.